# Counting Triangles Using SQL

Tags: sql, graph, geometry, counting

I am able to count the total number of triangles  for a undirected graph using the following query
But when i count it for each vertex when i execute the following query i just get the output of vertices which are part of a triangle it does not show the vertices which does not form a triangle for that type of vertices the count should be 0

select  e1.source, Count(*)
from edges e1 join
     edges e2
     on e1.dest = e2.source join
     edges e3
     on e2.dest = e3.source and e3.dest = e1.source and e2.source < e3.source 
group by e1.source;

Table Schema is as Follows

create table edges (source int not null, dest int not null);

Answer (score 2):

For this count, you can start at any vertex.  Then, for any two other points there are two ways to make a triangle -- e2 > e3 and e2 < e3.  Just put in one of these conditions so you only get one triangle, and then aggregate by the first point for the count:

```
select e1.source, Count(*)
from edges e1 join
     edges e2
     on e1.dest = e2.source join
     edges e3
     on e2.dest = e3.source and e3.dest = e1.source and e2.source < e3.source
group by e1.source;
```

Comment: Considering this as the inputs when the execute the above query i dont find all the vertices given as input                 create table edges (source int not null, dest int not null);

insert into edges values (1,2);
insert into edges values(1,3);
insert into edges values(2,1);
insert into edges values(3,1);
insert into edges values(2,3);
insert into edges values(3,2);
insert into edges values(2,4);
insert into edges values(4,2);
insert into edges values(4,5);
insert into edges values(2,5);
insert into edges values(5,2);
insert into edges values(5,3);
insert into edges values(3,5);

Comment: @RameshChalla . . . You should edit your question with sample data, not put it in comments.